# How to use data stored in java array into javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I have data stored in a 2-D Java Array 'Arr', I need to use it in JavaScript code.

Basically I am working on an **Organisation Chart** and I need to establish **Parallel Relationship** between two node based on some criteria. I have resolved that criteria in the back end but now to show the relationship on the UI, I need to use the resolved data on the front end.

*My JavaScript code is currently receiving Json data(to render/draw the nodes on front end) from java file through a JSP.* The problem I am facing is I can return only one Json object from the java method. That's why I am thinking of some other way to achieve this. Any other approach to use the array would highly appreciable.

One Approach I can think of is to make some global instance variables and use them to store data from this json returning method. And then send these instance variables to jsp through another java method. But can we a better approach?

Pls feel free to ask futher information.

Comment: please add some examples of the data, the outcome and the code, you tried.

Comment: Why would you need "some global instance variables"?

Comment: Usually the way to do this is to change the Json object that you return so that it has an extra field which is the array that you need. Any reason you can't do that?

Comment: I did not think about that. Thank you. @RealSkeptic

Comment: @MauricePerry  Actually I am new to this task. I was thinking to send another Json object through a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what JSON values you're currently returning from your backend, but you can always wrap it in an object, and add your array:

```
{
    "data": { ... },
    "arr": [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
}
```